# Display notifications messages in angular8?

Tags: angular, notifications, angular8, angular-toastr

As I am new to angular can some one "How to display notifications messages in angular8"?
I had searched on google but it shows wide variety of implementations and all seem quite length to just display a message.
So can some one give a example or link which should I follow
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular does not know how to show notifications. You can show notifications any way you want.

Here are some examples of ways to show a notification:

- [Using Angular material's snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview)
- Using window.alert
- Creating your own component.
- Use the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Comment: I tried following this link https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/notifications/

Comment: But it is not able to find ng-uikit-pro-standard. Then I tried npm install ng-uikit-pro-standard  it also didn't work. Can you tell what I am doing wrong

Comment: I'm not sure. Are you importing the modules correctly into your app module? I haven't used ng-uikit-pro-standard before, so I can't tell for sure. But the module list is here: [Module List](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/modules/) If you are using ng-cli you can also install it using angular schematics: `ng add angular-bootstrap-md` [ref](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/)

Comment: Implemented it using ngx Toast. Thanks for the help